# Way to automate the actions on an app that is owned by a 3rd party

Tags: android

I need a way to automate the actions on an app that is owned by a 3rd party.  The basic operator is the ability to Tap buttons and and put text in input boxes.

The idea is, the tool I needed will always be running.  When it gets a notification, it will start the target app (Instagram), fill out forms and tap buttons, then exit.

Could you help me how can I do it? I have no idea at all. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for are called Share Intents. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html).

For example:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + imageLocalPath));
shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
activity.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

PS: I don't think you can automate actions as trigger the 'Post to Instagram' button, if that's what you're asking. I don't think their API lets you upload automatically either. The best thing you can do is have the app notify you to press 'Post to Instagram' and fill out the necessary fields/images/videos for you.